# Use linkage with custom distance

Tags: matlab, linkage, pdist

I would like to use the linkage function in matlab with a custom distance.

My distance function is in the form:

```
Distance = pdist(matrix,@mydistance);
```

so given a

```
matrix = rand(132,18)
```

Distance will be a vector `[1x8646];`

```
D_matrix = squareform(Distance,'tomatrix');
```

is a matrix `132x132` contaning all the pairwise distances between te rows of `matrix`

How can I embed `mydistance` in `linkage`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a call to `linkage` like this:

```
Z = linkage(Data,'single','@mydistance')
```

where 'single' can also be any of the other cluster merge methods as described here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linkage.html.

In other words, just put your function handle in a string and pass it as the 3rd argument to `linkage`. You cannot use the `'savememory'` function in `linkage` while using a custom distance function, however. This is causing me some frustration with my 300,000 x 6 dataset. I think the solution will be to project it to some space where euclidean distance is defined and meaningful but we'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using

```
tree = linkage(Data,'single','@mydistance')
```

like Imperssonator suggests, you can also use

```
dissimilarity = pdist(Data,@mydistance);
tree = linkage(dissimilarity,'single');
```

The latter has the benefit of allowing Data to be an object array with @mydistance using objects as arguments.